# "Fetching SVN revision history" error on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

Yesterday I move my Eclipse workspace following [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165135/moving-eclipse-workspace-from-to-new-directory) to a bigger partition. It works fine I got back all my projects. Except about one option:

My projects are managed with SVN, I can still commit or update, but when I want to get the SVN history (right click on a procject => Team => Show History) I got the following error:

```
'Fetching SVN revision history' has encountered a problem
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: The path is not a working copy folder.
svn: '/home/admin/workspace/myproject' is not a working copy
```

The workspace's old path was `/home/admin/workspace/` and the new one is `/media/1to/workspace/`.

It seems that there is still a hardcoded path on the history config. Do you know how I can find this path in order to correct it?

Comment: Could you add an English translation of that error message?

Comment: @AndréStannek done ;)

Comment: Did you copy the `.svn` directory in the project's root directory?

Comment: @alroc Yes when I moved my projects I moved `.svn` file too